# How to prove teleportation does not violate no-cloning theorem?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, entanglement, teleportation, no-cloning-theorem

For a given teleportation process as depicted in the figure, how one can say that teleporting the qubit state $|q\rangle$  has not cloned at the end of Bob's measurement?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I.e., if we have the entire initial state is written as follows

$$| q \rangle \otimes | \beta_{00} \rangle =(\alpha | 0\rangle+\beta | 1 \rangle ) \otimes \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}( |00\rangle+| 11 \rangle)$$ $$= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\alpha | 000\rangle+\alpha | 011 \rangle+\beta | 100 \rangle+\beta | 111 \rangle ),$$

then, in step three, we obtain the state (the system state collapses to one of four possible result after measurement),

$$|\psi \rangle \equiv\{ |00\rangle \frac{\alpha | 0 \rangle+\beta | 1\rangle}{2}+| 01 \rangle \frac{\alpha | 1 \rangle+\beta | 0\rangle}{2}+| 10 \rangle \frac{\alpha | 0 \rangle-\beta | 1\rangle}{2}+| 11 \rangle \frac{\alpha | 1 \rangle-\beta | 0\rangle}{2} \},$$

where the right two-qubit is for Alice and the superposed qubits with corresponding probabilities $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are for Bob

hence we can no longer write

$$| q \rangle_A \otimes | \text{something} \rangle_B,$$

namely, Alice's $| q \rangle_A$ dissapeared.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by after the measurement, we obtain the state

|ψ⟩≡{|00⟩α|0⟩+β|1⟩2+|01⟩α|1⟩+β|0⟩2+|10⟩α|0⟩−β|1⟩2+|11⟩α|1⟩−β|0⟩2}?  Is this correct? You don't have it written in the Bell basis vectors. And your measurement is supposed to collapse your vector to either one of the four Bell basis terms. So why do you say it's obtained after measuring?

Comment: After "measurement" you **do not** get the state you wrote down: $$|\psi \rangle = \{ |00\rangle \frac{\alpha | 0 \rangle+\beta | 1\rangle}{2}+| 01 \rangle \frac{\alpha | 1 \rangle+\beta | 0\rangle}{2}+| 10 \rangle \frac{\alpha | 0 \rangle-\beta | 1\rangle}{2}+| 11 \rangle \frac{\alpha | 1 \rangle-\beta | 0\rangle}{2} \}.$$ That is incorrect. Please re-read the teleportation protocol from the Wikipedia page I linked in my answer.

Comment: I re-edited it!

Comment: @bilanush Is the idea that I cannot re-write the state as a product of the initial state implies that the latter had broken?

Comment: Yes. I believe so. But what you wrote even after editing looks wrong. You are supposed to get in the left side bell basis vectors .

Comment: @bilanush But I didn't work in Bell's basis , instead, the state is written in computational basis

Comment: Well, it's not correct. Because the vectors on the right side appear the same as when having bell basis in the formula so if can't be correct.  On the left sides instead of having 00 or 01 etc what you mean to get is actually a B00 B01 etc

Comment: What I have written is from a book of quantum information theory, I think the author didn't make any mistake here

Comment: @bilanush This *is* correct. I think what you're talking about is the state at step 1. Steps 2 and 3 have converted the Bell basis into the computational basis.

Comment: @DaftWullie Well, this could be correct only by chance but I don't believe it is. (Ok I didn't see he is talking about after measurement because he skipped a the representation in bell basis)  .  Anyways according to the teleportation I learned you aren't supposed to get 00(a0+b1) + 01(a1+b0) etc... But rather B(a0+b1)... Etc.  That's the first two qubits at Alice hands are Bell basis vectors.  And then you collapse to one of the states. Hard to me to believe that you can right the same expression and still switch B00 by 00 and B01 by 01... Etc.  Unless it's a coincidence.

Comment: Anyways, it's not smart to show it in computational basis. The whole point is to write the first two qubits in bell basis then perform a bell basis measurement . How to perform it , is more technical. It's not the point of teleportation.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, *carefully* read through the [formal presentation of the protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_teleportation#Formal_presentation) as described on Wikipedia. Secondly, there's nothing to prove as such here. It is evident from the teleportation protocol itself.

Yes, at the conclusion of the teleportation protocol, Bob's qubit certainly will take on the same state as Alice's qubit's *initial* state i.e. $|q\rangle$. However, Alice's qubit will now exist as an inseparable part of an entangled Bell state. You haven't really been able to create a "copy" of Alice's qubit, in the sense that Alice's qubit's initial state is "destroyed" in the process and is no longer $|q\rangle$.

In (crude) analogical terms, in the quantum teleportation protocol you "cut and paste" the state $|q\rangle$ rather than "copying and pasting". So there's no violation of the [No cloning theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-cloning_theorem)!

Answer (score 3):

Cloning means the generation of $|q\rangle|q\rangle$ from $|q\rangle|0\rangle$.  This is not what happens in teleportation. Teleportation is kind of a swap operation, i.e. something like $|q\rangle|0\rangle \to |0\rangle|q\rangle$.